# Is it possible to use going to future in that case

Tags: future-tense

my name **is going to** ring you a bell  is it grammatically correct? My name is not a person so can I use it ?

Comment: My name is going to ring a bell ***for you***.

Comment: *My name is going to ring a bell **with** you*. When used literally (sounding a bell to attract someone's attention), we usually use ***for***, but when used literally (of something which stirs / will stir a memory in the addressee), it's nearly always ***with*** (but ***for*** can be used, and may be considered more suitable if the prompting of that memory is an obviously desirable result for the addressee, which probably isn't the case in the cited context).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"[**going to**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/future/future-be-going-to-i-am-going-to-work)" is used to speak about future plans and intentions; to predict something that we think is certain to happen; to give commands or state that something is obligatory.

It might be possible if you predict this to happen in the future. it is, nevertheless, grammatically correct and, yes, you can use "**to be going to**" with inanimate objects.

I would understand it as, "*once you hear my name it will ring a bell (remind you of something maybe)*".